# How to import Keras Tokenizer to Java Deeplearning4j (DL4J)

Tags: java, import, deep-learning, keras

I have implemented Text Classification of 20 News Group data using Keras (2.1.4 on TensorFlow). The accuracy is decent 0.87. I am also able to save the model and tokenizer and use them in another python program to predict the class of text file. Using below to save model and tokenizer-

```
# creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
model.model.save('my_model.h5')

# Save Tokenizer i.e. Vocabulary
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

If you need to refere complete code - http://www.opencodez.com/python/text-classification-using-keras.htm

Now, I am looking to import Keras trained model and tokenizer into **Java Web Application**. Deeplearning4j provides an option to load Keras model with

```
MultiLayerNetwork network = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights("PATH TO YOUR H5 FILE")
```

But I could not find any option to load Tokenizer or its metadata.

As per my limited understanding, you would need the model and saved vocabulary metadata (tokenizer) to predict accurately.

Any help or pointers to achieve this are much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you file an issue on the deeplearning4j repo? We can take a look.

Comment: Thanks Adam,
I have created new issue with similar information - https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/5889

Answer (score 0):

You need an equivalent tokenizer, manage the vocabulary and vectorize in order to preprocess the text data and feed the model. You can easily create one tokenizer that mimics the Python one using [Java Regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). You can also check the [Stanford NLP Group software in Java](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/) and [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/).

For vectorization, check the Deeplearning4J's [DataVec](https://deeplearning4j.org/datavec), vectorization and ETL (Extract Transform Load) Java library. Maybe more interesting, check the Deeplearning4J [NLP Functionality](https://deeplearning4j.org/nlp).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be to create a classifier web service in Python (using Flask or other Python web framework) and expose calls to that web service to exchange  data in JSON/XML with a Java based web app.

Comment: Thanks Claude. Yes this could be another approach to achieve the results. I have created new issue on DL4J, will see if it gets any attention.